# Using HP 15-ay135nd as docked

Tags: docking

I want to use my laptop 'docked' using the HDMI and external keyboard + mouse. Problem is: When closing the cover the OS shutsdown in powersaving mode...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not close the cover?

Comment: Then no space to put my cup of coffee!

Answer (score 0):

Found option 'When cover is closed' in system settings...